# Entity Framework string length validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to save a string with a length larger than 2000 characters, but the Entity Framework validation "hangs" the string size in 2000 and returns me error message:

> The Value field must be a string or array type with maximum length of
>   '2000'.

In the database the field is `VARCHAR (8000)` and in the entity is defined MaxLength of 8000

Model

```
public class TermoUso : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid TermoUsoKeyId { get; set; }
    public virtual TermoUsoKey TermoUsoKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8000)]
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("varchar"));

        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(8000));

        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more code? The Model that you're using.

Comment: Have you tried applying the max length attribute to the data objects property?

Comment: Is it possible that you created EF model when your DB field size was 2000, then increased column size without updating EF model?

Comment: from the beginning the entity is with MaxLength defined in 8000, I am using code first

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: Could you show your dbcontext class in OnModelCreating and try to inspect element and see validation message of Texto property.

Comment: Delete from your model the entity and add the table again.

Comment: @Jsperk did not work...

Comment: Show the view markup. Are you using a ViewModel or editing your entity model directly? The error message does not even mention `TextTo`

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'StringLength':

```
public class TermoUso : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid TermoUsoKeyId { get; set; }
    public virtual TermoUsoKey TermoUsoKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

StringLength is a data annotation that will be used for validation of user input.

From MSDN: Specifies the minimum and maximum length of characters that are allowed in a data field

MaxLength is used for the Entity Framework to decide how large to make a string value field when it creates the database.

From MSDN: Specifies the maximum length of array or string data allowed in a property.